# HTML5 Server Sent Event Servlet on Tomcat 7 buffers events until socket close

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to add a server side event servlet to my web application.  Below is the code for my servlet: ( Several different versions )

Using getOutputStream():

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/hello"}, asyncSupported = true)
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2889150327892593198L;
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream");   
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        try{
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

                out.print("id: "+ i +"\n");
                out.print("data: "+ System.currentTimeMillis() +"\n\n");
                out.flush();
                response.flushBuffer();

                System.out.println("time sent:"+ System.currentTimeMillis());
                System.out.println("IsCommitted:" + response.isCommitted() );
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)  
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.close();    
    } 
}
```

Using PrintStream:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream");   
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    try{
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

            writer.write("id: "+ i +"\n");
            writer.write("data: "+ System.currentTimeMillis() +"\n\n");
            writer.flush();
            response.flushBuffer();

            System.out.println("time sent:"+ System.currentTimeMillis());
            System.out.println("IsCommitted:" + response.isCommitted() );

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)  
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    writer.close();

}
```

An Async Version using https://github.com/mariomac/jeasse

```
SseDispatcher dispatcher = null;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    System.out.println("test started.  Async mode.");
    startThread();
    dispatcher = new SseDispatcher(req).ok().open();
}

private void startThread() 
{
    Thread thread = new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override public void run() 
        {
            System.out.println("Thread started");
            try {
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Sending message " + i);
                    onGivenEvent("message"+1, System.currentTimeMillis()+"" ) ;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dispatcher.close();
            System.out.println("Thread ending");
        }
    };

    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.setName("testsse");
    thread.start();
    System.out.println("Starting thread");
}

public void onGivenEvent(String eventName, String data) throws IOException 
{
    if( dispatcher != null)
    {
        dispatcher.send(eventName, data);
    }
}
```

For all version I'm using curl to validate it:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json"  -X GET http://localhost:8080/testsse/hello
```

The output only comes at the end when the connection is closed by the server.  If the servlet does not close the connection you never get the output.

I need the events to arrive after the server sends them, and not when the connection is closed.  What am I doing wrong?  This cannot be the way its supposed to work.

I've googled and tried many examples and they all suffer from this same issue.

I've tried many different versions of tomcat 7.0.67, 7.0.34, 7.0.62.   I'm using 64 bit version of JDK 8.0.65 on Windows or JDK 8.0.45 on Linux.

Does anyone have this working?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this.  I switched to using [Jersey SSE](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html) and it functions as expected.

I could never get the above solution to function correctly.  The Server buffered all the IO until the connection closed. I tried all kinds of flushing and manipulating the buffer size.

Hopefully this helps... Start with another framework such as Jersey SSE.